# Volatile keyword in microcontrollers

Tags: c++, c, microcontroller, volatile

The `volatile` keyword tells the compiler not to optimize the variable which is prefixed. The variable may change during run time by unknown source (not known by the compiler) maybe by an external interrupt etc.

Is there any other advantage of `volatile`?
Does `volatile` apply to reading from files?

Comment: volatile helps the compiler when it makes optimizing runs.

Comment: Are you sure the compiler knows all the interrupts and takes that into account when compiling the code?

Comment: The `volatile` keyword does no such thing. Seek clarification from within [section 5.1.2.3p4](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#5.1.2.3p4).

Comment: without `volatile` how can you define and access memory-mapped registers?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc The same way we typically define and access memory-mapped files.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour no, registers will be defined like `#define SFR (volatile char *)0x1234`. There's no OS for you to get memory-mapped files

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc You've never heard of "memory mapped files"? Not everything in this world is [confined by your experiences](http://fallacyfiles.org/volvofal.html)... StackOverflow is forever.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour Do you even know what [memory mapped I/O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_I/O) is? "Memory-mapped I/O (*not to be confused with memory-mapped file I/O*) uses the same address bus to address both memory and I/O devices – the memory and registers of the I/O devices are mapped to (associated with) address values". Moreover, in simple microcontrollers how do you call a system function to map files to memory? And those registers are not files for you to map

Comment: @undefined behaviour. Please, give me a code example where you avoid the use of volatile accessing a register of an AVR ATmega168? (I.E.: the TCNT1 register) [ATmega168 datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc2545.pdf)

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc, Sergio: Could it be he is talking about memory-mapped peripherals using a device driver that actually maps the registers to user-space using Linux filesystem? Remember: in Unix everthing is a file. And iirc there is such a driver/functionality in Linux. Through use of the MMU, these pages could very well be tagged strongly ordered/non-shared, enforcing access. However, I still do not see how the compiler would be kept from reordering accesses or caching within the same function. And this is not Linux-related.

Comment: @Olaf. Yes, in Unix everything is a file! Glory! But under some of those functions there's an hardware, there're low levels functions which can't use the memory mapped I/O ... The Topic is not about Linux, is more general. I think the compiler can't imagine that the content of a memory area changes in an asynchronous way respect the flow of the code it's compiling, this fact is what it happen with hw registers, then, if they are not declared volatile, the compiler have no notice of that (the same is for memory shared between distinct processes or ISR).

Comment: @Olaf.  That is my point.  Often I read criticism about the use of volatile, normally who does these criticisms never worked with MCUs, but only with computers with SO as Linux/Windows and not managing interrups in their real behaviour.

Comment: @SergioFormiggini: I could not have worked that long as an _embeded engineer_ for important companies. if I would not know that already! Apparently, you did miss _my_ point: "undefined behaviour" seems to think  it is always the same. And for Linux, there is apparently a method to map the IO-space to to memory space of a regular application much like a file (not sure, but it might even be that simple as to mmap a file of sysfs or so to get the hardware-registers properly mapped). Then one could use the same mechanics as for normal files. that's what _he_ might be up to_ - **not me**.

Comment: Btw: a compiler has very litte "imagination". It might assume, but only as much as the standard defines. Otherwise, it has to prove (or apply proved rules). As I already stated: even for mmap-ped peripherals, it would require to use volatile at least; _presumed_ these address blocks are handled strong ordered at least by the hardware (that would be an entry in the MMU page-tables).

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand all the discussion! I've no doubt about your knowledge! :) It may be  I'm prejudiced with who compares behaviors related to hardware with high level software functionalities.

Comment: @Olaf. Yes, what you're saying is what I think. For sure it's (obviously) impossible that a general C compiler recognizes the difference between a memory cell and a memory mapped register and is impossible the compiler guesses that another process is allowed to modify a memory area.

Comment: @SergioFormiggini: That is clearly given by the standard. C by itself does not have a concept about concurrency. (Disclaimer: C11 threading additions are 1st optional and 2nd library based and/or left to the implementation, not the compiler as for control flow).

Comment: @Olaf there's no MMU for you in the ATmega and most other 8-bit or even 16-bit microcontrollers. Moreover those registers already have an address their own. You can't regard them as a file and map them to memory again

Comment: The problem is to understand the difference between targets. If I'm writing a driver that shall be fast is better don't use libraries, but pure code ... If I'm writing a program to elaborate data I might need of such libraries ... However I see stupid the use of libraries where I may use volatile.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: And none in the S08, 6502, Z80, 68000, 80286, 68HC11, 8051, ARM Cortex-M0/1/3/4/7, ARM7TDMI, PIC16/18, PIC32 and many more. Please stop telling me what I already know, smartass. I really have no further idea how to make clear that was not directly related to the AVR, but the what "undefined" might have thought about.

Comment: @SergioFormiggini: Same for you actually. I'm out, it's going in circles.

Comment: In a general contest is obvious that a memory mapped register is an object that when is managed has to be used without optimizations ... If I write `*REGX |= 2; *REGX |= 1`; might be so much different from `*REGX |= 3;` ... :) ... Probably undefinedbehaviour was speaking about the use of volatile for something different from memories and registers ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> `volatile` keyword says to compiler do not optimize the variable which is prefixed with, the variable may change during run time by unknown source(not known to compiler) may be by an external interrupt etc.

No. The `volatile` keyword does not tell the compiler to disable or not optimize a variable; the `volatile` keyword tells the compiler that the variable (or rather the memory that the variable represents) may be modified externally to the program.

This has the effect that the compiler is no longer able to do the necessary analysis to determine if various optimizations are safe (that is functionally equivalent), so the compiler does not perform those optimizations. This is a necessary side-effect, but not the primarily purpose for the existence of the keyword.

The usage of `volatile` as a somewhat or slightly portable hack of acting like a `pragma` to disable the compiler's optimization is a fairly common pattern. Outside of embedded programming, this may be its most commonly encountered usage for application programmers.

> The compiler knows all the interrupts of that controller. So in that case how the `volatile` keyword helps?

The `volatile` keyword means the memory contents can be modified outside of the program's control, either in another process, thread, or by external signals such as a hardware interrupt.

Compilers don't "know" about interrupts, there may be system header files distributed with a compiler that define *symbolic names* for an interrupt, but that does not mean the compiler understands them.

> Is there any other advantage of `volatile`?

Not that I can think of, beside what's described here.

> [Does] `volatile` appl[y] to reading from files?

Except when used as an form of inter-process communication (IPC) or as a semaphore, the contents of a file are normally controlled by a single process, so the usage of `volatile` is not necessary.

Comment: Nice explanation Mr.mctylr, thank you. Now i got clear picture of how volatile keyword acts.

Comment: And one more question, Can i assume I/O connected ADC as example. So ADC value changes anytime from outise world, this is not known to compiler.

Comment: Yes an memory mapped I/O connection, such as an ADC input, is a good example of a case where `volatile` keyword may be used. The variable's contents are controlled outside of the program's control (i.e. it is controlled by the ADC), and so may change without the compiler knowing.

Answer (score 5):

`volatile` actually tells the compiler the value of the variable may be changed *outside its control flow*. The most popular would be an interrupt or interrupt handler or a hardware register. For the latter, the compiler does actually *not* know when its value changes. Nor does it for an interrupt, as that only occurs at run-time.

Note that C assumes a single threaded program flow; the compiler does not have any idea of concurrent processes. Even less does it make assumptions on the underlying hardware.

For all other variables, the compiler may (gcc for instance actually *will*) assume it has full knowledge about the system state.

Also accesses to `volatile` variables may not be reordered with respect to each other. This is important when e.g. a UART requires the status register to be read first and then a new char may be stored to the transmit data register. For most MCUs, only this sequence will clear the flags properly. Very important: non-vloatile variables *may* be reordered as much as the compiler wants to (as long it does not change the program logic, of course).

Note that `volatile` does not guarantee atomicity and correct behaviour on multicore-systems or does protect against re-ordering of accesses by the hardware (memory controller, etc.) (well, the AVR is a bit underprivileged with all these ;-). That is one reason for locks and why hardware-areas in the memory map are treated special by the hardware (ordered, non-shared).

**Edit:**

[Here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.2/gcc/Volatiles.html#Volatiles) is detailed how gcc handles volatile objects. gcc is known to strictily keep to the standard for optimizations. Anything not forbidden might be exploited for optimization. Classic embedded compilers like IAR are often much more conservative.

Comment: More specifically, in an Arduino, the `volatile` keyword *directs the compiler to [produce code that] loads the variable from RAM and not from a storage register.*  See http://www.arduino.cc/en/reference/volatile

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Ehm..  I was sure we're talking about C and AVR, not arduino. (btw: thanks for the edit).

Comment: You had me doubting so I went back and double-checked.  Sure enough, I was right the first time; Arduino uses AtMega processors, and the AtMega128 is cited in the question.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Well, yes (could have told you, too)! But ATMega does not use arduino necessarily ;-).

Comment: I don't know what the processor cross-pollination is.  But it seems pretty clear that the motivation is to ask the processor to go get the value *from its source,* rather than relying on a (possibly stale) cached value in a register.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: That's what I presumed. But not that alone (I added another point). Problem is also reordering. On larger system all this becomes much more complicated due to bus-buffers, distributed caching, etc. However, it is still not about Arduino (wouldn't have answered for that).

Answer (score 4):

The C / C++ standard for volatile means that reads and writes to a volatile variable will be a read or write to that location in memory, and that the order of operations to a volatile variable will be maintained. Since reads from a volatile variable are actually reads of the variable in memory, then if the variable is updated by an outside source such as another thread, process, or hardware, the value read will reflect any writes that occurred before the read. It's meant to be used for memory mapped hardware interfaces such as I/O memory mapped ports. It doesn't prevent out of order operations on other variables. I assume that the order of operations on multiple volatile variables is maintained, since this would be needed for hardware / software handshake.

Microsoft compilers optionally extend the meaning of volatile so that read / write operations to volatile variables are effectively done as a [memory barrier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier) and can be use for communication between threads. [MSDN volatile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12a04hfd.aspx) .

Comment: Note that the order is only maintained for a single process. And even that is not guaranteed as any instance in-between might reorder accesses. That's the reason atomics have been introduced in C11.

Comment: Well, yes - and no - Yes: for simple atomic operations, but this is often enough (just think of a very wide counter (larger than CPU-word width) which is incremented by one thread and read by multiple others - **for example**). However, have a look at atomic_compare_exchange(). This is the basis for many non-blocking & lock-less algorithms (e.g. lists). Just search for this.

Comment: Then you might re-read and concentrate on the [`memory_order` constraints](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic/memory_order). There you will find the barriers. `stdatomic.h` however also provides an explicit fence (aka barrier, actually two) instruction. In general, atomicity is a system-wide concept. However, DMA and peripheral registers are not included, I'd say it is all components which implicitly execute the current program (that composed of the compilation units discussed).

Comment: MSDN is definitively not the relevant standard and a very bad reference for `C` - most will not accept this as such. They deliberately do not even support C99. You really should first understand before confronting. If in doubt, read the standard (the last draft [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) is available for free download).

Comment: @Olaf - Then I don't understand the point of your first comment. In my answer, I clearly state that the standard volatile does not act as a memory barrier, but that Microsoft compilers (Visual Studio) optionally (the default for X86) cause volatile to act as a memory barrier.

Comment: Just again: get away from that Microsoft documentation! MS *does not support recent C99**, much less C11. Note also, that the standard does define minimum requirements; it does not forbid a compiler to be more strict. Why should it - it still would execute correctly if all variables were treated volatile. Just read the reasoning about the introduction of stdatomic - not just for C, but also for C++ (which is intentionally pretty much the same). And look for something better than MSDN.

Comment: You pointed out that the "order of operations to a volatile variable will be maintained". I stated that "instances in-between" (CPU and actual storage) might still reorder or even suppress - 3rd level cache) these "operations (whatever that would be - variables can be read or written - accessed - nothing else). For the order of different volatiles: I did answer that in my response to the question, btw.

Answer (score 1):

`volatile`, as you mentioned, is a guarantee that the compiler will perform no optimizations regarding the variable. If a variable's value isn't changed in a scope as determined by the compiler, it *may* cache the value to a register and refer to that cached value for efficiency so it doesn't waste cycles fetching the actual value from main memory.

I'd imagine in a microcontroller with such limited amounts of registers, you wouldn't want to cache variables constantly.

Comment: What would be an "optimized variable"? I just can think of proper alignment. And: that is not just a matter of scope, but system state.

Comment: THe problem with volatile in general is, while the compiler does gurantee that, the hardware might actually not.

Comment: Right, interrupts and waking from sleep/brownouts are examples. I guess this is what you mean by system state.

Comment: System state is the whole "state of the system". Just think of all storage cells (variables, constants, CPU registers, peripheral registers, bus-interface registers, ... - **everything**) as a veeerrrry wide state-variable of a FSM - finite state machine, read about that). Interrupts are actually _not_ part of that, but the interrupt flag bit would be, as much as the interrupt enable bit, etc.