# C Global declared in ISR

Tags: c, arm, embedded, cortex-m, codewarrior

I am evaluating Freescale's Kinetis Design Studio for their ARM series microcontrollers.  I was looking at an [example](http://www.element14.com/community/community/designcenter/kinetis_kl2_freedom_board/blog/2014/08/03/frdm-k64f-kinetis-design-studio-kds-tutorial-toggling-an-rgb-led-using-interrupts)  as a basis to do my first "blink an LED" project.  When using variables shared between my main program and an ISR such as a counter, I would typically define a volatile global in main.c  and reference it as extern in the ISR.  Their example shows it exactly the opposite and they also don't use the volatile keyword.  I have never seen it done this way.  Is there an advantage to this?  BTW, my program works just fine either way.

Comment: Show your code. This is no tutorial site.

Comment: If you can show a small section of the relevant pieces of code, that would be helpful.

Comment: Note that you still have to _define_ the global at global scope. And you should not _declare_ a global variable at function scope. (actually, if that is an interface variable, you should provide a header file with that inteface, including the _declaration_ of the variable (unless all is in one file, of course).

Comment: The example you refer to is *not* "from Element14", it has been posted on a community forum that happens to be hosted by Element14.  Its just someone on the Internet; there is no guarantee of quality or good practice.  You will often be disappointed if you expect "found code" to always be "good code".

Comment: @Olaf : perhaps he intended *main.c* rather then `main()`; that would make more sense.

Comment: @Clifford: Possibly. He also confuses _declaration_ and _definition_ apparently.

Comment: I see that the [profile of the example's author](http://www.element14.com/community/people/bheemarao/profile) indicates the he is an Element14 employee, but nonetheless I would not assume that a hardware VAR to necessarily be an expert software developer; so my previous comment stands.  You should perhaps post a comment to the blog in question if you are concerned enough.

Comment: @Olaf, Clifford is correct, I meant to say main.c, not main().

Comment: For a typical pattern, use @Clifford's approach. That is good design practice and hides implementation details. You should, however, work on your understanding of _declaration_ and _definition_, These are very important terms in C and help very much to understand your postings (if used correctly). - just a well-meant hint

Comment: @Olaf: I am not seeking a tutorial.  I have been writing embedded C code for years for the HCS08 processor family using the UEStudio IDE and Cosmic's tool chain.  This is my first time with ARM and Codewarrior.  Codewarrior is over the top complex in my opinion with "Processor Expert" abstracting all the lower level code.  I thought maybe the "rules had changed" but I guess not.  Thanks all for pointing out that the example I cited was not an official Element 14 example.  I missed that.

Comment: @Olaf: Point well taken.  Thanks

Comment: The link you posted is written by a complete _amateur_! For starters you _do not_ connect a button to an interrupt-triggered pin! Any embedded programming student can tell him why: electromechanical signal bouncing. So regardless of whether your have a RC filter in the hardware or not (which is most likely not the case here) there's a fat chance that the signal bounce will spam multiple interrupts all over your code, completely ruining any real-time performance.

Comment: And because of the signal bounce you most likely need a simple digital filter, which there is no sign of here either. You need to add such a filter and you need to heed Clifford's sound advise regarding program design.

Comment: Since you meant main.c rather than main(), how about editing the question to fix that and other issues? That is what the comments in SO are intended for rather than "discussion".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The missing `volatile` is an error ([albeit a common one](http://www.embedded.com/electronics-blogs/beginner-s-corner/4023801/Introduction-to-the-Volatile-Keyword)) that itself should be a quality warning.  The choice of where to instantiate a global is arbitrary, but from a cohesion point of view, it makes sense to keep data that relates to the interrupt *with* the interrupt.  That said, the use of the [global data](http://www.embedded.com/electronics-blogs/break-points/4025723/A-pox-on-globals) is itself an indication of dubious quality and practice.

A better pattern that makes use of data encapsulation is:

---

*interrupt.c*

```
...

volatile static int counter = 0 ;
void interruptHandler()
{
    counter++ ;
}

int interruptCounter{ return counter } ;
```

### ...

*interrupt.h*

```
...

extern int interruptCounter() ;

...
```

---

*main.c*

```
#include "interrupt.h"

    ...

    int icount = interruptCount() ;

    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know the codewarrior suite. However, in general, `volatile` tells the compiler the variable is changed outside normal control flow as given by the program code.

Historically, embedded compilers were quite forgiving about not using 'volatile' and/or implemented some strategies to support inexperienced programmers who did not know about optimizations and "forgot" `volatile`. This will result, however, in badly optimized code, expecially for the ARM platform (it was less of a problem with HC08&Co MCUs which had to load every variable from memory anyway).

While it might be that CW is still that tolerant, compilers which highly optimize code like gcc are not that forgiving and optimise much more radical. If you forget `volatile` or barriers for such compilers, you might end up with an empty main-loop, for instance.

Even *if* your code runs fine for now, this might change once you enable optimizations or change a minor (possibly unrelated) aspect.

Very well meant advice from an long-term embedded developer: use `volatile`. Use it sparsely and well thought (more details can be found [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30472561/volatile-keyword-in-microcontrollers/30472710#30472710)), but use it!

Comment: I know I have encountered a "missing volatile" bug for a variabled shared with an ISR on one of the Codewarrior compilers. I suspect if it was for either 68HC08, S08 or S12. Codewarrior is generally rather crappy at optimizing though, so usually this bug doesn't happen for that reason.

Comment: Yep... competent embedded programmers are rare, unfortunately. Nowadays I seem to spend most of my time doing damage control on programs written by others. There's always the programs written by "hardware guys gone programmer" or "assembler dinosaur gone C", that come with a vast amount of beginner-level bugs and incredibly poor design. The only proper longterm solution to that, beyond acute first aid, is to burn the source code with fire and re-write it from scratch...

Comment: I was going to add "PC programmer gone creative" to those other two categories, but indeed they produce completely different kinds of problems, compared to the others :)

Comment: Problem is, with all the fancy IDEs and "standard" libraries/frameworks, it becomes even harder to make a manager understand good firmware still takes time - possibly even more if you use that stuff. They just know the shiny PowerPoint from a marketing guy and think it is not more complicated than a simple clicked-together GUI. "No programming, all auto-generated".

Comment: BTW - isn't this lack of volatie just related to project settings and optimizations being turned off? This tends to be true for many example projects for STM32 and LPC I've seen. Not that it is a good practice, just the opposite, but still it happens often.

Comment: @alagner: Problem is that embedded programmers still worked assember-only while the rest already used C or hiher level languages already. These were mostly electrical engineers without CS background. So when they changed to C, the first embedded compilers had to accout for them not knowing about optimization pitfalls and not using `volatile` and other concurrency concerns. Problem is that many of these people still resist (sic!) to learn writing correct good software - and one reason C has such a bad reputation. And another reson things like MISRA were enforced - for the bad of good developers

Comment: @alagner: ... who be already cautions of the pitfalls of C, but are hindered by MISRA to use modern constructs which actually improve code quality. (MISRA very long stuck at C90).